# Machine Epsilon: MatLab vs Maple

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, scientific-computing, maple

I'm learning about machine epsilon in single and double precision and comparing values from different programs. For example, in matlab the following code:

```
>> format long
>> eps
```

gives 2.220446049250313e-16. But the following code in Maple:

```
> readlib(Maple_floats);
> evalhf(DBL_EPSILON);
> quit;
```

gives -15
.2220446049250314 10 (where -15 is exponent).

There is a slight difference in output between the two programs. Maple appears to round up from 3 to 4. What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: In Maple, `evalhf(DBL_EPSILON)` gives `.222044604925031308 10^-15`, which is the same as `eps` in Matlab. So what's the issue?

Comment: Which kind of calculation are you doing in which 30+ floating point matters really? :~

Comment: It's designed to prove a point about machine epsilon, which I'm not understanding.

Comment: What version of Maple are you using? Is it very old? The **readlib** command should be unnecessary. Try again with using it. I get 2.22044604925031308e-16, *i.e.*, I get two more digits than you.

Comment: @NKN There are might be more to this than first suspected. Note that for an addition of two numbers (and this is the whole calculation, eg `nPebblesOnBeach + handfulOfPebbles`) it may be ok with a precision 10^-16. Further, a multiplication like `area = pi*r^2;` would probably only need a lower precision in most cases. However, assume you have a large matrix. This one may also be badly conditioned. See for example `cond(rand(N))`. Here you definitely may care whether machine epsilon is 10^-16 or (maybe a bit rough, but...) 10^-10.

Comment: @patrik you are right, but in the question he is comparing the 30th (approx.) digit to be a 3 or a 4 that in case that the console is rounding the number to show, it can be an easy misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that Maple (and Matlab) are showing you a radix-10 representation of a hardware double precision floating point number.

So perhaps you should be more concerned with the underlying hardware double precision value.

```
> restart:
> kernelopts(version);

       Maple 2015.0, X86 64 LINUX, Feb 17 2015, Build ID 1022128

> X:=Vector(1,datatype=float[8]): # double precision container
> p:=proc(x) x[1]:=DBL_EPSILON; end proc:
> evalhf(p(X)):

> lprint(X[1]);
HFloat(.222044604925031308e-15)

> printf("%Y\n", X[1]);                                       
3CB0000000000000
```

That last result is "formatted in byte-order-independent IEEE hex dump format (16 characters wide)", according to the documentation.

So, what does Matlab give you when you `printf` its `eps` in the equivalent format? A quick web-search seems to reveal that it'll give 3CB0000000000000 alongside that 2.220446049250313e-16 you saw.

In other words: the hardware double precision representation is the same in both systems. They are representing it differently in base 10. Note that the 
base 10 value displayed by Maple has 18 decimal places. The digits past the 15th are artefacts of a sort, stored so that in general internally stored numbers can round-trip correctly for repeated conversion both ways. Note that hardware double precision relates to something *between* 15 and 16 decimal places. So if you want to compare between the two systems you could (and likely should) compare the stored hardware double precision values and not the base 10 representations past the 15th place.